# Angular Material - Input a number range (min value and max value) in a single form field

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to create a form field where you can enter 2 values to specify a range, [similar to what Angular material's date range picker looks like  (second example)](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview), except with raw numbers instead of a date.

[This is what I want.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03UTS.png)  You should be able to click into the form field, decide to enter the min field, max field, or both.  Trying this in the Material's date range picker does not work because as soon as the form field becomes unfocused, it is turned into a date.

Here's my relevant code snippet below that doesn't work:

```
// component.ts

this.searchForm = new FormGroup({
  'minValue': new FormControl(),
  'maxValue': new FormControl()
} )

// component.html
<form [formGroup]="searchForm" (ngSubmit)="search()">

  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Range</mat-label>
    <mat-date-range-input >         
      <input matInput formControlName="minValue" placeholder="Min Value">
      <input matInput formControlName="maxValue" placeholder="Max Value">
    </mat-date-range-input>
  </mat-form-field>

</form>
```

Comment: no default solution, only 2 inputs and style them like in material, else don't forgot about angular forms & validation

Comment: yeah, I guess there's no way around it.  Thank you for your input!